# Chai assertion error when comparing arrays

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-runner, chai

I have encountered a weird error when trying to assert that a result should equal to an array, when using Chai.

**Code Example**

```
   describe("compare array", function() {
        it("should return an empty array", function() {
            const result = getEmptyList(); // just a silly example
            expect(result).to.equal([]);
        });
   });
```

**Result**

```
  × compare array
    PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0)
  expected [ find: [Function] ] to equal [ find: [Function] ]
  AssertionError@C:/Code/example/node_modules/chai/chai.js:9449:24
  assert@C:/Code/example/node_modules/chai/chai.js:239:31
  assertEqual@C:/Code/example/node_modules/chai/chai.js:1387:18
  methodWrapper@C:/Code/example/node_modules/chai/chai.js:7824:30
  test/unit/utils/example.js:5:32
```

When I instead expect the length of the result to equal zero, it works fine. Can anyone share some insights to why this is happening. Why is `[ find: [Function] ]` all of a sudden expected, instead of `[]` as was desired?

I am using Karma as my test runner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since one array is never `===` to another, for arrays you need the [`deep`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep) qualifier for [`equals`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal):

```
expect(result).to.deep.equal([]);
// --------------^^^^^
```

From the docs:

> Causes all `.equal`, `.include`, `.members`, `.keys`, and `.property` assertions that follow in the chain to use deep equality instead of strict (`===`) equality.

Comment: Thanks TJ, you made my day!

Comment: @ProgrammerPer - Glad to help! I belatedly realized that it had to be a duplicate, and found the canonical for it.

Comment: Great, no worries!